# AngularJS ng-model throws "undefined is not a function" UNLESS I also print out the model

Tags: angularjs

I haven't been able to produce a JS-Fiddle that reproduces this yet, but maybe somebody has an idea.  I have a fairly deeply nested model.  In the following code, the commented out line works perfectly.  The value shows and I can update the model without issues.  The line below it, with the only difference being a lack of value="", throws a lot of "TypeError: undefined is not a function" errors and it doesn't work at all.

```
<tr ng-repeat="v in opened.points[opened.selectedPoint].variables">                                                     
<!-- <td><input type="text" ng-model="v.name" value="<% v.name %>"></td> WORKS-->                                        
<td><input type="text" ng-model="v.name"></td>  <!-- FAILS -->                                                                    

</tr>
```

Any idea where to BEGIN debugging this thing?

EDIT:  Note that I replaced {{ }} with <% %> so as not to conflict with my Django template engine.

Comment: This would be much easier to troubleshoot than to speculate on.  Can't share your code?  Maybe your issue could be more easily duplicated on http://plnkr.co?

Comment: You have unclosed input tags.

Comment: lucuma: HTML5 doesn't require closing tags like that.  Adding /> to the end doesn't change this behaviour.